# ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge two datasets that have the same column 'Value' but it gives me this error : can not merge DataFrame with instance of type

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import pie, axis, show
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.choice = input
        self.file = 0

def read(self):
    if self.choice == ("merge"):
        self.file = pd.read_csv('bbc.csv')
        self.file = pd.read_csv('cnn.csv')
        print(pd.merge('bbc.csv', 'cnn.csv', on="Value"))
```

Comment: What is the error you are finding? What are the contents of the two CSVs? Please be descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the two opened .csv as self.file... and then you're trying to merge two strings. Instead, define the dataframes as variables and then merge:

```
if self.choice == ("merge"):
    self.file1 = pd.read_csv('bbc.csv')
    self.file2 = pd.read_csv('cnn.csv')
    # print(pd.merge(self.file1, self.file2, on="Value"))
    print(self.file1.merge(self.file2, how='inner', on="Value"))
```

Comment: This worked! But it did not do it's job quite right.

I got : Empty DataFrame
Columns: [GeographyCode_x, DateCode_x, Measurement_x, Units_x, Value, GeographyCode_y, DateCode_y, Measurement_y, Units_y, Qualification]
Index: []

Comment: It gives me an AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'file1'. :/

Comment: this means you have not defined file1 in your DataSet class

Comment: When i define them and set them to 0 or to pd.read... the output is again: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [GeographyCode_x, DateCode_x, Measurement_x, Units_x, Value, GeographyCode_y, DateCode_y, Measurement_y, Units_y, Qualification]
Index: [].

Comment: Are you certain that there are common values in "Values" in each dataframe? This output means that there are no common values. If you use  how='outer', on='Value', indicator='True you can check which df each row has come from. left = self.file1, right=self.file2